# Adjective declension in a prepositional phrase

Tags: adjective, declension

The following sentence is from a description of an ability in the video game, Pillars of Eternity 2. It is  the first clause that concerns me here:

> Der Barbar schleudert eine große mit Wut erfüllte Waffe auf das Ziel, die beim Auftreffen in einem Feuerball explodiert.

My question is:
shouldn't *erfüllte* be *erfüllten* in this case due to the dative preposition *mit*? Does the fact that *Waffe* being the direct object of *schleudert* nullify the dative case that normally follows *mit*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The dative caused by *mit* is on "Wut", not on "Waffe".

And because both "große" and "erfüllte" belong to "Waffe", which is accusative, they need to be accusative as well.

Whether it's good style to write about "filling a weapon with rage", is disputable, however.

Comment: +1, this is a question of *scope*. The word "erfüllte" **is not within the prepositional phrase**, therefore the word "mit" is irrelevant.

Comment: I guess *mit Wut* is a prepositional phrase that works here as an adverb modifying the verb *schleudert*. Is it a common style to insert such a prepositional phrase which doesn't modify the noun *Waffe* between the two subsequent adjectives *große, erfüllte*? Does that give *mit Wut* a special emphasis due to its unusual position?

Comment: The sentence is bad style. A "weapon filled with rage" appears weird because people are in rage, not weapons (at least in German, maybe it's acceptable in English, although I doubt it). Grammar-wise the sentence is correct, but its weirdness makes it harder to read and understand, which impedes the grammatical analysis.

Comment: @RHa  Good observation! With proper content, the sentence gets indeed clearer: *Der Konditor schleudert eine große, mit Schokocreme gefüllte Waffel auf das Brautpaar, die beim Auftreffen in einem Fett- und Sahneregen zerstiebt.*

Comment: It is indeed quite strange, but I think there is magic in that game, so who knows.

Comment: @RHa This is indeed a very good analysis and should be a part of the answer in order to get the complete picture. When I read this sentence, I couldn't associate *mit Wut* with *erfüllte*; Unconsciously I was associating it directly with the subject. In contrast to *@Christian Geisrlmann* example below where I associated *Schokocreme* unconsciously to *gefüllte*. Nice comment and nice explanation, thanks.

Comment: @RHa although I would certainly not defend the literary merits of the source material, the context is a magical fantasy world. "a rage-imbued weapon" would probably be my best translation, with the premise being that this is somehow possible in this world. Apologies for posting nerdy stuff on the forums!

Comment: @Killian Foth thank you for that clarification.